# How to "place-hold" regex matches in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, contentplaceholder

If I have a multiple match regex like:

```
var matches = string.match(/\s*(match1)?\s*(match2)?(match3)?\s*/i);
```

and if my string that I am testing is like this:

```
var string = "match1 match3";
```

is there a way to output this array values:

```
matches[1] = "match1";
matches[2] = "";
matches[3] = "match3";
```

Notice: what I would like is for the regex to match the entire thing but "place-hold" in the array the matches it does not find.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There already is a "placeholder". e.g.  `"match2".match(/\s*(match1)?\s*(match2)?(match3)?\s*/i);` returns `["match2", undefined, "match2", undefined]` `[0]` is the complete regex match and `[1] [2] [3]` are the individual groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already is a "placeholder". Unmatched groups pop an array index matching the group number with an undefined value. e.g.

```
var someString = "match2";
var matches = someString.match(/\s*(match1)?\s*(match2)?(match3)?\s*/i);
```

`matches` now has

`["match2", undefined, "match2", undefined]`

Element `0` is the complete regex match and elements 1-3 are the individual groups

So you can do for example...

```
// check if group1
if (typeof matches[1] != 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare the string to the regexes, just do an Array join.Something like,

```
matches[1] = "match1"; 
matches[2] = "";
matches[3] = "match3";
var mystring = mathches.join("");
```

The joining character could be anything. You could also do,

```
var mystring = mathches.join(" ");
```

EDIT:
   Not sure from the problem description, but i think you want the regex to output an array.Something like

```
 text = "First line\nSecond line";
 var regex = /(\S+) line\n?/y;
```

would give,

```
var match = regex.exec(text);
print(match[1]);  // prints "First"
print(regex.lastIndex); // prints 11
```

More about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: That is not exactly what I was asking for... I am looking to have the regex output an array that looks like that, not compare the matches to the original.

Comment: the output of a regex comparison can only be "true"/"false"

Comment: [`.match`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) match does this as does [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: I just want to be able to detect if a certain part of the the conditional regex match did not find anything to match.